# What are the correct steps to have a supplementary security domain with DAP verification?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, securitydomain

It has been a time that I am searching for a best practice on installing and configuring a supplementary security domain (SSD) with its own secure channel keyset and DAP verification so that no one cannot install any applet except signed ones on the card.
Unfortunately I could not find any good discussion reaching to the result on this matter. Best discussions where [this](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/issues/248) one in the GlobalPlatformPro github, and [this](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/issues/29) one from GPShell discussoins. These are what I am doing:

First, I create an RSA keypair using `openssl` as:

```
genrsa -out ./rsaPrivateKey.pem 1024
rsa -pubout -in ./rsaPrivateKey.pem -out rsaPublicKey.pem
```

and [sign the applet](https://github.com/martinpaljak/capfile) with the rsa private key as:

```
capfile -s ./rsaPrivateKey.pem applet.cap
```

Then I make the below steps to install and personalize the SSD:

1. Install an SSD (if supported by the card) from the package `A0000001515350` on the card and give `DAPVerification` privilege to it. I do this by `gp -domain A000000151535041 -privs DAPVerification --allow-to` command by GlobalPlatformPro which results in:

   ```
   Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
   Note: using default AID-s for SSD instantiation: A000000151535041 from A0000001515350
   ```

   that installs the SSD with DAP verification privilege as `gp -l` confirms it:

   ```
   Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
   ISD: A000000151000000 (OP_READY)
        Parent:  A000000151000000
        From:    A0000001515350
        Privs:   SecurityDomain, CardLock, CardTerminate, CardReset, CVMManagement, TrustedPath, AuthorizedManagement, TokenVerification, GlobalDelete, GlobalLock, GlobalRegistry, FinalApplication, ReceiptGeneration

    DOM: A000000151535041 (SELECTABLE)
         Parent:  A000000151000000
         From:    A0000001515350
         Privs:   SecurityDomain, DAPVerification, TrustedPath

    PKG: A0000001515350 (LOADED)
         Parent:  A000000151000000
         Version: -1.-1
         Applet:  A000000151535041

    PKG: A00000016443446F634C697465 (LOADED)
         Parent:  A000000151000000
         Version: 1.0
         Applet:  A00000016443446F634C69746501

    PKG: A0000000620204 (LOADED)
         Parent:  A000000151000000
         Version: 1.0

    PKG: A0000000620202 (LOADED)
         Parent:  A000000151000000
         Version: 1.3
   ```
2. Next I need to set a secure channel keyset on this domain and a DAP key (an RSA public key) so that the domain can verify the applet signature before installing that. I think a secure channel keyset can be set by the global platform `PUT KEY` command (is that correct? after selecting the SSD just do the PUT KEY? or do I need an authentication before that?) or do it using gp pro `gp -d -v -i -sdaid A000000151535041 --lock 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F` using default keys resulting:

   ```
   ...
   Card locked with: 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
   Write this down, DO NOT FORGET/LOSE IT!
   SCardEndTransaction(ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0)
   SCardDisconnect("ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0", true)
   ```

   and adding the DAP key by `gp -d -v -i -sdaid A000000151535041 -new-keyver 0x73 -put-key rsaPublicKey.pem -key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F` comming to:

   ```
   gp -d -v -i -sdaid A000000151535041 -new-keyver 0x73 -put-key rsaPublicKey.pem -key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
   Reader: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0
   ATR: 3BD518FF8191FE1FC38073C821100A
   More information about your card:
       http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BD518FF8191FE1FC38073C821100A

   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - (I)SD AID: A000000151535041
   A>> T=1 (4+0008) 00A40400 08 A000000151535041 00
   A<< (0018+2) (22ms) 6F108408A000000151535041A5049F6501FF 9000
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected block size: 255
   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
   A<< (0045+2) (16ms) 9F7F2A4790D3214700000000002345406114204839000000000000000012594530363131340000000000000000 9000
   [WARN] GPData - Invalid CPLC date: 4530
   CPLC: ICFabricator=4790
         ICType=D321
         OperatingSystemID=4700
         OperatingSystemReleaseDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
         OperatingSystemReleaseLevel=0000
         ICFabricationDate=2345 (2012-12-10)
         ICSerialNumber=40611420
         ICBatchIdentifier=4839
         ICModuleFabricator=0000
         ICModulePackagingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
         ICCManufacturer=0000
         ICEmbeddingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
         ICPrePersonalizer=1259
         ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate=4530 (invalid date format)
         ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID=36313134
         ICPersonalizer=0000
         ICPersonalizationDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
         ICPersonalizationEquipmentID=00000000

   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0042 00
   A<< (0000+2) (13ms) 6A88
   [DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(IIN): N/A
   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0045 00
   A<< (0000+2) (12ms) 6A88
   [DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(CIN): N/A
   Card Data:
   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
   A<< (0000+2) (12ms) 6A88
   [DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(Card Data): N/A
   Card Capabilities:
   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0067 00
   A<< (0000+2) (10ms) 6A88
   [DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(Card Capabilities): N/A
   A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
   A<< (0020+2) (15ms) E012C00401018010C00402018010C00403018010 9000
   Version:   1 (0x01) ID:   1 (0x01) type: DES3 length:  16
   Version:   1 (0x01) ID:   2 (0x02) type: DES3 length:  16
   Version:   1 (0x01) ID:   3 (0x03) type: DES3 length:  16
   A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 F84B1304E9CCCB89 00
   A<< (0028+2) (44ms) 00002345406114204839010200008858A82BFF2ADFE98536447C2ABB 9000
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: F84B1304E9CCCB89
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: 00008858A82BFF2A
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with key version 1 (0x01)
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Will do SCP02 (8)
   [DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Card keys: {ENC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, DEK=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, MAC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F}
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: DFE98536447C2ABB
   [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: 841DAA1B25EA1743
   A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 841DAA1B25EA17431205662BFF634819
   A<< (0000+2) (25ms) 9000
   SCardEndTransaction(ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0)
   SCardDisconnect("ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0", true)
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[0x73]"
      at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
      at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
      at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
      at pro.javacard.gp.GPCommands.intValue(GPCommands.java:1037)
      at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:429)
   ```

Which give the error as can be seen from the logs. I don't know the reason for this error!

and when I try to load the signed applet with `gp -to A000000151535041 -key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F -load applet.cap` I get:

```
Applet loading failed. Are you sure the CAP file target is compatible with your card?
INSTALL [for load] failed: 0x6985 (Conditions of use not satisfied)
```

looks the DAP key is not set! I'm stock right here and I don't know wether the DAP key is set or not and where am I missing!

What are the correct steps? and where am I making mistake(s)?

### Appendix 1:

As suggested I changed the version of my GP Pro to:

```
gp -version

GlobalPlatformPro v20.01.23-0-g5ad373b
Running on Windows 11 10.0 amd64, Java 11.0.20 by Oracle Corporation
```

and ran the command below:

```
gp -d -v -i -sdaid A000000151535041 -new-keyver 0x73 -put-key rsaPublicKey.pem -key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F

GlobalPlatformPro v20.01.23-0-g5ad373b
Running on Windows 11 10.0 amd64, Java 11.0.20 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[*] ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0
[ ] ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
[ ] ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader SAM 0
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contactless Reader 1
SCardConnect("ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0", T=*) -> T=1, 3BD518FF8191FE1FC38073C821100A
SCardBeginTransaction("ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0")
Reader: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0
ATR: 3BD518FF8191FE1FC38073C821100A
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BD518FF8191FE1FC38073C821100A

[DEBUG] GPSession - (I)SD AID: A000000151535041
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 00A40400 08 A000000151535041 00
A<< (0018+2) (63ms) 6F108408A000000151535041A5049F6501FF 9000
[TRACE] GPSession -  [6F]
[TRACE] GPSession -      [84] A000000151535041
[TRACE] GPSession -      [A5]
[TRACE] GPSession -          [9F65] FF
[DEBUG] GPSession - Auto-detected block size: 255
[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(CPLC)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
A<< (0045+2) (17ms) 9F7F2A4790D3214700000000002345406114204839000000000000000012594530363131340000000000000000 9000
[WARN] GPData - Invalid CPLC date: 4530
CPLC: ICFabricator=4790
      ICType=D321
      OperatingSystemID=4700
      OperatingSystemReleaseDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      OperatingSystemReleaseLevel=0000
      ICFabricationDate=2345 (2012-12-10)
      ICSerialNumber=40611420
      ICBatchIdentifier=4839
      ICModuleFabricator=0000
      ICModulePackagingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICCManufacturer=0000
      ICEmbeddingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPrePersonalizer=1259
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate=4530 (invalid date format)
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID=36313134
      ICPersonalizer=0000
      ICPersonalizationDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPersonalizationEquipmentID=00000000

[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(IIN)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0042 00
A<< (0000+2) (12ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(IIN): N/A
[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(CIN)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0045 00
A<< (0000+2) (12ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(CIN): N/A
Card Data:
[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(Card Data)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
A<< (0000+2) (13ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(Card Data): N/A
Card Capabilities:
[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(Card Capabilities)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0067 00
A<< (0000+2) (11ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(Card Capabilities): N/A
[TRACE] GPData - GET DATA(Key Info Template)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
A<< (0002+2) (9ms) E000 9000
[TRACE] GPKeyInfo -  [E0]
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[INFO] GPSession - Using card master keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for null
[TRACE] GPSession - Generated host challenge: CBF9FD30F7E7CC91
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 CBF9FD30F7E7CC91 00
A<< (0028+2) (48ms) 0000234540611420483901020040E44E27742BEE237DE8DBC26EEA8F 9000
[DEBUG] GPSession - Host challenge: CBF9FD30F7E7CC91
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card challenge: 0040E44E27742BEE
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card reports SCP02 with key version 1 (0x01)
[INFO] GPSession - Diversified card keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for SCP02
[INFO] GPSession - Session keys: ENC=AB72716E9FD59960B411D3302BE52BA4 MAC=9AC631F205CADC0651DE5D5B59D57C2A RMAC=2B8D43219A94F5B243BCF1EDD20EFAF5, card keys=ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for SCP02
[DEBUG] GPSession - Verified card cryptogram: 237DE8DBC26EEA8F
[DEBUG] GPSession - Calculated host cryptogram: B529E033BCDB174E
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 8482010010B529E033BCDB174E
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 B529E033BCDB174E55AB271149BAD1D1
A<< (0000+2) (25ms) 9000
[TRACE] SCP02Wrapper - MAC input: 84D800019173A180E29DE024AA485070A1CD8A028901096BADFFE68B510DF933938CDB13AC7BFAD6C51A43094E841EEC140046664F537E7F9C3D0A552016C1350B6ABA4648826125243145C4DBC9045A968FE05E7B7AACE3315CEF54AB7555FAD5520F7DADC4C4CB39A22BF9092A620B992B5B273C00FA3C46D6E3C7AB0197BBF69D88F9CFFF641BA00301000100
A>> T=1 (4+0145) 84D80001 91 73A180E29DE024AA485070A1CD8A028901096BADFFE68B510DF933938CDB13AC7BFAD6C51A43094E841EEC140046664F537E7F9C3D0A552016C1350B6ABA4648826125243145C4DBC9045A968FE05E7B7AACE3315CEF54AB7555FAD5520F7DADC4C4CB39A22BF9092A620B992B5B273C00FA3C46D6E3C7AB0197BBF69D88F9CFFF641BA003010001007D8AC84F6F39BA77
A<< (0000+2) (30ms) 6985
PUT KEY failed: 0x6985 (Conditions of use not satisfied)
```

Comment: Which version of GP are you using? The code didn't parse new-keyver properly a while back but it got fixed with https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/commit/0014bdaff06bd2d3ea462c955d57df59b4ce9a57 which has been included since 19.05.16 as per https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/issues/118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GP Pro version doesn't support the format you are using for --new-keyver. Same problem can be found in https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/issues/118. This was first fixed in pre-release version [19.05.16](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases/tag/19.05.16)

I would suggest using the latest release of [20.01.23](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases/tag/v20.01.23) where the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Asthor for your response. I changed GP version as you suggested to 20.01.23. I think the problem for key version has been solved. I added the corresponding logs to Appendix 1 to my question. I think now the problem is about authentication! I'm quite sure that I have used the default key (4041...4F) but it returns 0x6985!

Comment: Not actually sure why it returns 0x6985 and I don't have a setup where I can test this. I know using -sdaid is deprecated and the recommendation is to use -c/--connect but unsure that would actually help. 

Outside of that only suggestion is that the key is wrong somehow but you are using the default key. But your put key operation seems correct otherwise according to https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/wiki/Supplementary-Security-Domains and https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/next/tests/sce70.sh

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not solving this completely but the error:

For input string: "[0x73]"

comes form the keyversion `-new-keyver 0x73`

Use a different format, maybe without 0x or consult the manual of`gp`